# Network profile shows 117 score on my top voted question, but it actually has 118 score

Tags: bug, network-profile, score

In [my SE network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3659449/cool-guy?tab=top), I see 117 score for my top voted question. But if you visit the question, you'll find that it has 118 score. The last vote I got on that question was at least a week ago, IIRC. Bug?

Comment: I just up-voted you in order to see if it updates. It is cached obviously, and I guess the cache didn't update for a while. So should we blame caching? Yes, we should!

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but could you tell me what "_cache_" means? I've heard it from several places, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes. It is now updated. You can retract your vote.

Comment: No need to. I like the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching should be blamed. After I voted on the question, the stats updated. I guess the stats updating is triggered by a vote on the post, which fails sometimes for unknown reasons.

I guess a developer should check why the updating could fail, and if it is a broader problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy, if you feel like it, keep the question open so a developer could check this post. Maybe your question will get skipped when you accept my answer. (Although I appreciate you accepting my answer)

Comment: Might be related to un-upvote as hinted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270979/152859): such event might not trigger the network profile synch process.